# 'Response' object has no attribute 'user'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, drf-queryset

I am getting error AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'user' for the below code I have written

I am trying to get the user info from the context and create a notification model. I am getting the above error while returning the statement. I don't understand why I am getting this error

***Model***

```
class CourseNotification(models.Model):
   uid = models.UUIDField(
      primary_key=True,
      default=uuid.uuid4,
      editable=False,
      unique=True)
   course = models.ForeignKey('Course.Course', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
   user = models.ManyToManyField('Profile.myUser',null=True)

   def get_user(self):
      return [i for i in self.user.all()]

   def __str__(self):
      return self.course.course_title
```

***View***

```
class CourseNotificationView(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = CourseNotification.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CourseNotificationSerializer
    authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

def get_queryset(self):
    if self.request.user.email is not None:
        profile = myUser.objects.get(email=self.request.user.email)
    if profile is not None:
        notification = CourseNotification.objects.filter(user=profile)
        return notification
    else:
        return Response(data={"User": "Unauthorized User"}, status=HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(self.get_queryset(), many=True)
    return Response(data=serializer.data)
```

***Serializer***

```
class CourseNotificationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CourseNotification
        fields = '__all__'

def create(self, validated_data):
    users = self.context['request'].user
    subject = validated_data['course']

    if users is None and subject is None or subject == "":
        raise serializers.ValidationError({"Invalid": "Subject could not be Invalid"})

    checkNotification = self.checkNotification(users, subject)
    if checkNotification is not None and checkNotification.status_code == 200:
        return checkNotification

    validate_subject = self.validateSubject(users, subject)
    if validate_subject.status_code == 200:
        return validate_subject

    get_data = CourseNotification.objects.create(course=subject)
    get_data.user.add(users)
    get_data.save()
    return Response(data=get_data, status=HTTP_201_CREATED, content_type="application/json")

@staticmethod
def checkNotification(users, subject):
    get_data = CourseNotification.objects.filter(user=users, course=subject)
    if get_data:
        for data in get_data:
            data.user.remove(users)
            data.save()
        return Response(data=get_data, status=HTTP_200_OK, content_type="application/json")

@staticmethod
def validateSubject(users, subject):
    get_data = CourseNotification.objects.filter(course=subject).exclude(user=users)
    if get_data:
        subject = CourseNotification.objects.get(course=subject)
        subject.user.add(users)
        subject.save()
    return Response(data=get_data, status=HTTP_200_OK, content_type="application/json")
```

I am trying to add data to the model through API. I am facing the problem

Comment: Is the error coming from  `users = self.context['request'].user` ? Can you please add the error you're getting??

Comment: Hi, @KhalilAlAhmad I am getting error `return checkNotification` or `return validate_subject` whenever they called. data created successfully. when I am trying to return the above line I am getting the error